# Spring binding doesnt works using ajax without form

Tags: ajax, spring, binding

Why I can not bind data sent by Ajax to the controller **Option** modelAttribute in the controller ?

My ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: { "option.price": 5.99,
          "option.owner": "15463"},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
  if (data == "error") {
    $('.error-message').show();
    $('.success-message').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('.success-message').show();
    $('.error-message').hide();
  }
}
```

My Option class

```
@Entity
public class Option extends Entity {
  private User owner;
  private Float price;

  /* getters / setters */
}
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String saveSinglePtaOptions(@ModelAttribute("option") Option option)
```

And the request successfuly go into this controller method mapping. The **option** object is always null.

I have a converter that convert String id to an User object by retrieving from the database but its never been called. And Im pretty sure the converter works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with  `@RequestBody` instead of `@ModelAttribute`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!@RequestBody works but it couldn't bind the owner field. When I set with a string id, I got a "bad request". but if I set to null, it binded correctly (price value and owner to null). That why I use ModelAttribute to trying to use the converter but nothing its binded there... I believe that @RequestBody didn't call the converter that why I've got a bad request.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is more simple decision, but I would do it like this (I didn't test it but think it should work):

Use `@RequestBody` and write your own implementation of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to catch arguments of type `Option`:

```
public class OptionArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return methodParameter.getParameterType().equals(Option.class) ? true : false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
            ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
            NativeWebRequest webRequest,
            WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        Object option = getRequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor()
            .resolveArgument(parameter, mavContainer, webRequest, binderFactory);
        WebRequestDataBinder binder = new WebRequestDataBinder(option);
        binder.setConversionService(conversionService);
        binder.bind(webRequest);
        return option;
    }
}
```

And don't forget to register it. For example, in the `mvc:annotation-driven` tag:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="your.beautiful.package.OptionArgumentResolver"/>
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

This also could easily be modified to handle every attribute annotated with `@RequestBody` by changing `supportsParameter()` method body to:

```
return getRequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor().supportsParameter(methodParameter);
```